# Ubuntu Studio 18.04 and 19.04 hanging in installation

Tags: ubuntu-studio, vmware-workstation

I'm having trouble installing Ubuntu Studio on VMware workstation 12.
I'm using the ISO files downloaded from the Ubuntu website, specifying the hardware as needed (2 CPU, 4GB memory, 30GB disk) and then powering on the VM and starting the installation.
For both versions, it gets part way through then sits on the spinning cursor, nothing appears to be happening and no visible progress is being made.
Is this just a long install or is something wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the ISO files against their checksum?

Comment: No. I can view the checksum on the download page but what would I use (in Windows) to actually confirm the checksum of the downloaded file against that which has been published?

Comment: Apparently, there is a `certutil` program on Windows to do that.

Comment: Hmmm, MD5 hash is completely different, but the SHA256 was the same

Comment: Same thing is happening in VirtualBox. I can't even run it as a live machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, Ubuntu Studio does not support installation or running via Virtual Machine at this time. This is due to the power-hungry nature of the applications included, and as such, we have taken the stance not to support virtual machines.

Source: I'm the current Ubuntu Studio project leader.